# How to hide a child element from Xceed Magnifier?

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I am able to zoom using `Magnifier` (Xceed's control toolkit).
I have multiple controls in `Grid` that I want to get rid off `imageEditor` and `ListBox` controls from Magnifying Glass when it gets zoom.

My code is below.

```
<Grid>
      <wpfMagnifier:MagnifierManager.Magnifier>
          <wpfMagnifier:Magnifier x:Name="magnifiyingGlass"  Visibility="Hidden" 
                              FrameType="Circle"  Radius="240" ZoomFactor=".4" BorderBrush="#9cc63e" BorderThickness="9">
          </wpfMagnifier:Magnifier>
      </wpfMagnifier:MagnifierManager.Magnifier>
      <Image x:Name="cvT" >
      </Image>
      <imageEditor:UserControl1 x:Name="UserControlID1" Points="{Binding Points}" IsClosedCurve="{Binding IsClosedCurve}" />
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PointListBoxItemStyle}" x:Name="ItemsContainer" 
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ItemsContainer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="ItemsContainer_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="ItemsContainer_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
      <ListBox.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
              <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </ListBox.Template>
      </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

How to implement it?

Comment: introduce one more Grid which will contain only Image and Magnifier

Comment: Actually I am drawing Polygons and Lines on Image using  **imageEditor** and **ListBox**  control, So I can't introduce new Grid.